# Constructor with an empty mem-initializer-list and an empty body

Tags: c++, constructor, c++14, language-lawyer, ctor-initializer

Where can I find in the Standard (C++14) a clause stating that an user-defined default constructor with an empty *mem-initializer-list* and an empty body invokes the default constructor for each base class and for each member sub-object. For instance consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
class A{
public:
    A() {std::cout << "A" << '\n'; }
};

class Base{
public:
    Base() { std::cout << "Base" << '\n'; }
};

class Derived : public Base {
    A a;
public:
    Derived() {}
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
}
```

The constructors for both `Base` and `A` are called by the user-declared constructor `Derived()` with an empty mem-initializer-list and an empty body.

Comment: 12.6 might cover that

Comment: My first guess would be.... you would find the text somewhere near to the text where it talks about mem-initializer list and the initialization of base classes and their order, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the draft standard [N4527](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf) *12.6.2/9 Initializing bases and members [class.base.init]* (**Emphasis Mine**):

> **In a non-delegating constructor, if a given potentially constructed
>   subobject is not designated by a *mem-initializer-id* (including the case
>   where there is no *mem-initializer-list* because the constructor has no
>   *ctor-initializer*), then**
>
> (9.1) — if the entity is a non-static data member that has a
>   *brace-or-equal-initializer* and either
>
> (9.1.1) — the constructor’s class is a union (9.5), and no other
>   variant member of that union is designated by a *mem-initializer-id* or
>
> (9.1.2) — the constructor’s class is not a union, and, if the entity
>   is a member of an anonymous union, no other member of that union is
>   designated by a *mem-initializer-id*, the entity is initialized as
>   specified in 8.5;
>
> (9.2) — otherwise, if the entity is an anonymous union or a variant
>   member (9.5), no initialization is performed;
>
> (9.3) — otherwise, **the entity is default-initialized** (8.5).

**Note:** As [@Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant) pointed out in the comments below, in C++14 (N4141) "finalized" standard the above quote lies in paragraph 8 and not paragraph 9.

Comment: In C++14 (N4141) this is p8 instead of p9, otherwise looks good! +1 :-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant thanks for the point, unfortunatelly I don't I have a copy of the C++14 standard. I'll add a note though.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Exactly what version of the C++ 14 standard are you referring to?

From n4296:

> https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard
>
> Note:
>
> In some circumstances, C++ implementations implicitly define the
>   default constructor (12.1), copy constructor (12.8), move constructor
>   (12.8), copy assignment operator (12.8), move assignment operator
>   (12.8), or destructor (12.4) member functions. —end note

Also;

> A default constructor for a class X is a constructor of class X that
>   either has no parameters or else each parameter that is not a function
>   parameter pack has a default argument. If there is no user-declared
>   constructor for class X, a constructor having no parameters is
>   implicitly declared as defaulted (8.4). An implicitly-declared default
>   constructor is an inline public member of its class.